# Is there an easy way of implementing a radial basis function in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am a beginner in pytorch python library and want to implement  a Radial Baisis function(RBF) network. How does one look like in pytorch?

Comment: What kind of operations do you exactly need? It would be great if you can provide some equations or operations you want.

Comment: To be specific I want to know how to set initial parameters of the network.

Comment: Good, you may like to edit your problem and make it more specific.